# PcbNew invisible field still showing

Tags: pcb-design, kicad

I was editing a PCB and KiCAD crashed. When I restarted all fields that were previously invisible are now showing, even though their property is set to invisible.

Is this a bug? Or an option I can toggle somewhere. Like "Hide/show all hidden fields."

Opening other older PCBs is the same thing. fields set to invisible still show.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check to make sure that your "Hidden Text" item is deselected

[image: Hidden Text]

Comment: if the Layers Manager (Visibles) side bar is not enabled click top menu "Preferences" then click "Show Layers Manager". Your file that controls preferences may have been corrupted by the crash, you may want to check other color settings and preferences.

Comment: Thanks so much. I was looking for hours.